# Require to add content to a bug report using the (Android) app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, asking-questions, mobile-app

It seems some users experience trouble, specifically with the Android app. They fail making a good bug report here since they just hit the *Report an Issue* button in the app and then *Post Your Question* here in MSE.

The don't seem to understand they end up on another Q/A site where they have to form their question so *everybody* can understand it, not just the developer with the error logs.

We often see such questions in nothing more than the minimal required body that is auto-created by the app itself, like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285736/bug-report-for-a-galaxy-s3):

> [image]

Can we enforce that with the footer automatically inserted, users still need to add some explanation? Maybe a smart regular expression on the question body is enough.

Comment: Yes please! Adding a simple notice explaining what to do (e.i. explain the problem!) would be a big help too I think

Comment: related: [http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285736/bug-report-for-a-galaxy-s3](Bug report for a galaxy s3) I hadn't seen this recent feature request, if I had I would have directed Amanda over here.

Comment: This question was based on that report, so it would be hard to redirect her here... Thanks anyways.

Comment: But she (if the user is a woman)  didn't know about your post. You could have notified **and** explained to her.

Comment: Why? This feature request isn't going to help here. The close reason is enough to ask her to update her post.